# Different scores in each cross val folds?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I have about ~800,000 data points and highly imbalanced dataset with  <1% of the population being positive .
I used SMOTE sampling to up sample my minority class.

I used cross_val_score to do a 10 fold cross validation the scores for each fold are different.

```
score=[0.44813278, 0.7388535,  0.78964401, 0.74691358, 0.79084967, 
0.8411215 ,0.80981595, 0.80495356, 0.78947368, 0.39183673]
```

The first and last fold have very low results compared to the mean of this list.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you do stratified sampling?

Comment: @user2974951 yes I used stratified samples.

Comment: This may just be chance. Try doing another CV and see how the results compare.